# Does the rate of dissociation of PCl5 increase in presence of Cl2

Tags: equilibrium, erratum

I'm sorry if this is somehow inappropriate to ask but I've found a rather strange question on my text book that asks "Why does the rate of dissociation of $\ce{PCl5}$ increase in the presence of $\ce{Cl2}$ ?".

Somehow I couldn't find any relevant answer to this question, which led me to possibly believe that this might be a printing mistake. But nonetheless I wanted to ask if this particular case is an exception or not.

Comment: $PCl_5$ tends to decompose to $PCl_3$ and $Cl_2$. This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Chatelier%27s_principle ;)

Comment: According to Le Chatelier's principles the case is exactly opposite to the views of my question.I did figure this out myself.But I'm not sure if there is any particular exception in terms of PCl5 dissociation

Comment: "Exactly opposite"? Care to clarify? Additionally, are you sure you understood the idea (Le Chatelier's principle) correctly?

Comment: Yikes! I'm sorry but I've accidentally put my own explainations as my question in there.I've corrected them.Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: That edit completely changes your post...perhaps the question was stated incorrectly? Pretty sure the question has been wrongly worded, but you should wait for someone else to put in their opinion here. Also, where did you see this question?

Comment: I just think there has to be an error in the question itself, i.e. _increase_ should be _decrease_.

Comment: @air Yup, think so too. I edited the question to include the "erratum" tag (yes, it exists) :D

Comment: @Paracetamol I've found this in a chapter that deals with Equilibrium State and Le Chatelier's Principles on my Chemistry text book.I'm an International student and the Author is domestic, hence unrecognizable.

Comment: @Saad Meh, just asked. It's advisable to include excerpts, that are pertinent to your question, from whatever material you use. Perhaps a PDF version of the text is available online? In that case, try putting in the link at the end of your post. Cheers!

Comment: Please include the citation to the text you are using (no matter how obscure you think it is). If it is a published text book it should have and isbn, if it doesn't, it could just be a random statement off of a stranger in the street and has little more credibility.

Comment: I'm sorry but as I've told It's a domestic Author and the language is 'Bangla'

Comment: If you think you're up to it, try translating the excerpt to English and post that (alongside the original Bangla) in your question. A lot of users here use books/articles written in their native tongue. Take a page out of our beloved Moderator @Mart's book in this regard ;) [ https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/76959/what-did-actually-happen-when-staudinger-tried-to-synthesise-diamond ]